# Disable search option for resolv.conf

Tags: centos, resolv.conf

We are running a script that tries to resolve thousands of domains for a research project. The issue we are having is that a lot of domains are not resolvable for example `foo.com`. If we ping `foo.com` the system will do a lookup for `foo.com`. If that does not resolve, it will do a lookup for `foo.com.ourdomain.com`. It `/etc/resolv.conf` we had:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager

search ourdomain.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

The above result is expected since we had the search setting set. If we changed it to say:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager

search ourdomain.net
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

then as expected any non-resolvable query will be queried again with ourdomain.net at the end.

The issue that we have is if we remove the search line completely from `resolv.conf` then system goes back to using ourdomain.com as the search. What we want is if a DNS lookup does not resolve to NOT then look it up with the domain that WAS set in `resolv.conf` (which is also the domain of the box).

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to set the search option in /etc/resolv.conf to:

```
search .
```

so /etc/resolv.conf would look like.

```
search .
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

Comment: It works. It still has side-effect that the nonexistent FQDN will be resolved twice: as a FQDN and as a FQDN rooted to `.` from "search". Those are same domain on the wire, but it may double PPS in some corner-cases.